# Generate key/Encryption/Decryption for RSACryptoProvider and BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Key generated through RSACryptoProvider is work for BouncyCastle Encryption (using publickey) / Decryption (using privatekey) ?

```
 using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var pu = rsa.ToXmlString(false);               
            var pr = rsa.ToXmlString(true);               
        }
```

Also, how to generate key using BouncyCastle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to first question, yes, RSA is a standard and it doesn't depends on the libraries used.

Second, try this:

```
    public static void GetRsaKeyPair(out string privateXml, out string publicXml)
    {
        CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
        var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(secureRandom, 1024);

        var rsaKeyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        rsaKeyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair rsaKeyPair = rsaKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        var privateRsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)rsaKeyPair.Private);

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsaProvider.ImportParameters(privateRsaParameters);
            privateXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true);
            publicXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false);
        }
    }
```